# Add new attribute to magento shopping cart

Tags: magento

I just wanted to share an idea of creating a new attribute in #Magento and using it into shopping cart in effective way. People mostly load whole product just to get new attribute value in the cart page but this is a wrong approach. What is the better way is explained here:

http://deepakbhatta.com/magento-add-new-attribute-to-shopping-cart/

Comment: where is the question.

Comment: He wrote "I just wanted to share an idea of creating a new attribute" so it is not a question but more of a post

Comment: @KandarpBPatel Yes, its just a post which I want to share.